# How to change Strapi link inside a description to HTML link tag

Tags: reactjs, replace, split, axios, strapi

I'm creating a simple blog post project and when I put a link inside a description or body of the article it is created like this `[text](#)`.

When requesting the said article using axios.get in ReactJS and console logging the response gets the `[text](#)`.

How to change the `[text](#)` to `<a href='#' className='className'>text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Markdown to HTML library to convert it.

Comment: Depending on the converter you use I think. Maybe you have a feature on your converter that will let you add a custom class in your DOM elements